# The * operator must be applied to a pointer

Tags: c#, .net, casting, operators

Getting the error :

> The * opertaor must be applied to a pointer

```
public static void SetClass(decimal Value, string input)
{
    Utils.SetMemory(Offsets.ClassName, new byte[16]);
    byte[] Multiplier = new byte[] { 0x04 };
    byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
    Utils.SetMemory(Offsets.ClassName + ((uint)Value - 1 + * 0x10), Utils.Multiply(inputBytes, Multiplier));
}
```

If I remove the "+" thats in front of the "*" It says

> cannot convert from long to uint

So if converting it is the solution how would I do that?

Need This With Custom numericUpDown

```
Utils.SetMemory(Offsets.ClassName + ((uint)numericUpDown1.Value - 1) * 0x10, "Classes");
```

Want To Call Method Like

```
Stats.SetClass(numericUpDown Here.Value, text string here);
```

Im New To C#

Edit

```
public static void SetMemory(uint Offset, byte[] value)
{
    PS3.SetMemory(Offset, value);
}
```

Comment: You have an unusual style of programming. What's with the gratuitous `+` symbols? You've added 3 of them;.

Comment: Can you show the method definition for `Utils.SetMemory`

Comment: this part does not make sence to me `((uint) + Value + - 1 + * 0x10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this part `(uint)Value - 1 + * 0x10`. You are not following mathematical rules for adding and multiplication, `+` or `*` needs two operands. You are not supplying two operands. Here `+ * 0x10` there is two operator after each other and this cause a problem. If you want to add `0x10` to previous result remove `*` and if you want to multiply by `0x10` remove the `+`.

The problem with `cannot convert from long to uint.` error is that **maybe** `Offsets.ClassName` variable is of type `long` or `Int64`, The result of `Offsets.ClassName + ((uint)Value - 1 * 0x10)` statement is long because the result of `((uint)Value - 1 * 0x10)` is `uint` and when you have `long + uint` the result type would be `long`. Now you want to pass a long variable to a function which accepts `uint` and this cause error because there is no implicit conversion from `long` to `uint`.

Comment: Hmm I swear I tried that and it gave me an overloaded error but it works now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and realized I had just accidentally placed a comma if that helps anyone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34853596)